# Should [tag:publishing] be a synonym of [tag:publication]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The tag [publication](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publication) and the tag [publishing](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) seems to be very close, and the questions tagged 'publication' can be tagged 'publishing' in my opinion. So I think they can be synonyms.

If they can't, what is the difference between them? When have we to use the tag 'publication' instead of 'publishing'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The words themselves have a slightly different meaning, but in terms of the way these tags are used, there's no real difference between the tags.

I'd have no trouble making one a synonym of the other, unless someone else has an objection. It'd make it easier to find questions with these tags, I think.

Edit: Have created and approved the tag synonym.